# Hi i am trying to show error messages on the basis of status code but unfortunately getting response in console not on Client Display

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mern

Here is my code for the client

```
const submitFormData = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to publish post?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Confirm!'
        }).then(async (result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {

                const res = await companyJobPost(input)
                console.log("res", res)
                if (!res.status === 200) {
                    alert("JobId must be unique ")
                    return
                }

                else {
                    alert("Job posted successfully")
                }
            }
        })
    }
Here is the res from the console
```

{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}config: {url: 'http://localhost:8080/company/jobPost', method: 'post', data: '{"companyId":"610a4313ea5428258c5e689d","companyEm…":"1-year - 2-year","terminalDegree":"Bachelors"}', headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}data: {aprroved: false, rejected: false, status: 'pending', _id: '6145fd8a77b1ba2f80403241', jobId: '01w4', …}headers: {content-length: '430', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}status: 200statusText: "OK"[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Your `if-else` looks wrong. Remove `!` from if condition and switch the error msg

Answer (score 0):

#Updated answer

```
alert(JSON.stringify(yourObjectVariable));
```

Comment: no, not working

Comment: Make sure you haven't checked the "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" checkbox on your browser

Comment: .then(async (result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                companyJobPost(input).then(response => alert("Success"))
                    .catch(err => {
                        alert(err)
                    })
            }
        })

Comment: this code shows me an alert with status code 400 message but not the res message

Comment: From your code in the question, you've written `console.log(res)` then it will obviously console log the result. I hope you're asking to print this res, right ?

Comment: If you want to alert the result object,  `alert(JSON.stringify(yourObjectVariable));
`

Comment: Hey @zaka awan did Alert worked ?

Comment: yes i have used JSON.stringify and it works

Comment: Great. I've updated my answer. if someone encounters the same issue. it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong alert. I think this should fix your problem.

`import { Alert } from "react-native";`

```
Alert.alert(
  "Alert Title",
  "My Alert Msg",
  [
    {
      text: "Cancel",
      onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
      style: "cancel"
    },
    { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
  ]
);
```

Read https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert for more info.

Comment: this is not react-native code ,i am working on react js